# Append columns to Pandas DataFrame in for loop

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping

I'm adapting the code in this [tutorial](https://medium.com/swlh/web-scraping-weather-data-with-selenium-webdriver-69a7b501fac) to get historical weather data. I want to retrieve several different quantities (temperature, dew point) for a range of dates. The idea is to save each quantity in a column of a pandas DataFrame, while each row shows times/dates. I'm having problems with appending/merging the quantities (when they are generated in a for-loop) in an existing DataFrame.

My MWE is:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
pd.options.display.max_columns = None
pd.options.display.max_rows = None
from datetime import date, timedelta
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

lookup_URL = 'https://www.wunderground.com/history/daily/us/ny/new-york-city/KLGA/date/{}-{}-{}'

# range of dates
start_date = datetime.strptime('1 January 2015', '%d %B %Y')
end_date = datetime.strptime('3 January 2015', '%d %B %Y')
df = pd.DataFrame()

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('headless')

# Create an instance of ChromeDriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='./chromedriver.exe', options=options)

while start_date != end_date:
    print('gathering data from: ', start_date)
    formatted_lookup_URL = lookup_URL.format(start_date.year, start_date.month, start_date.day)
    driver.get(formatted_lookup_URL)
    # wait until website is fully loaded before getting data
    # time data
    rows = WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//td[@class="mat-cell cdk-cell cdk-column-dateString mat-column-dateString ng-star-inserted"]')))

    for row in rows:
        thehour = row.find_element_by_xpath('.//span[@class="ng-star-inserted"]').text
        # append new row to table
        df = df.append(pd.DataFrame({'Date':[start_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')], 'time':[thehour]}), ignore_index = True)

    # other variables
    cols = ["mat-cell cdk-cell cdk-column-temperature mat-column-temperature ng-star-inserted",
            "mat-cell cdk-cell cdk-column-dewPoint mat-column-dewPoint ng-star-inserted"]
    name = ['temp_degF', 'dew_pt_degF']

    for ii in range(len(cols)):
        rows = WebDriverWait(driver, 0). \
               until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//td[@class=' + '"' + cols[ii] + '"' + ']')))
        for row in rows:
            data = row.find_element_by_xpath('.//span[@class="wu-value wu-value-to"] ').text
            # append new rows to column
            df.append(pd.DataFrame({name[ii]:[data]}), ignore_index=True)
            #df.merge(pd.DataFrame({name[ii]:[data]}), left_index=True, right_index=True)
            #df = pd.concat([df,pd.DataFrame({name[ii]:[data]})], axis=0)
            #df = df.append(pd.DataFrame({name[ii]:[data]}))
            #df.merge(pd.DataFrame({name[ii]:[data]}), left_on='True')
    
    start_date += timedelta(days=1)

print(df.head(5))
```

Comment: What is the format of what you want to append and the format of that to which you are appending

Comment: `DataFrame.append` is not like `list.append`--it returns a new, separate DataFrame with the appended data and does not modify the original DataFrame in-place. Thus `df.append(pd.DataFrame({name[ii]:[data]}), ignore_index=True)` probably does not  have any effect.

Comment: @ ifly6 The `temp_degF` and `dew_pt_degF` variable are floats, and the `df` is a pandas DataFrame. I'll also want to append other parameters that are strings eg. wind direction.

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign df = when you use the append operation.  Otherwise you don't actually modify the df.  See this toy example.

```
row1list = [True, False]
row2list = [True, True]
row3list = [False, 2.2]
row4list = [False, np.nan]
df = pd.DataFrame([row1list, row2list, row3list, row4list],
                  columns=['column1', 'column2'])

df.append(df)
print(df)    # unaltered original
#    column1 column2
# 0     True   False
# 1     True    True
# 2    False     2.2
# 3    False     NaN

df = df.append(df)
print(df)
#    column1 column2
# 0     True   False
# 1     True    True
# 2    False     2.2
# 3    False     NaN
# 0     True   False
# 1     True    True
# 2    False     2.2
# 3    False     NaN
```

Note you may want to reset index after appending everything so that you don't have any duplicate indices.

```
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
print(df)
#    column1 column2
# 0     True   False
# 1     True    True
# 2    False     2.2
# 3    False     NaN
# 4     True   False
# 5     True    True
# 6    False     2.2
# 7    False     NaN
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried `df = df.append(pd.DataFrame({name[ii]:[data]}), ignore_index=True)` but the resulting table contains `NaN` entries for `temp_degF` and `dew_pt_degF` columns

Comment: If you append df1 to df2 and df1 has a column that is not in df2, or vice versa, pandas fills the mismatched column with NaN.  Is that what's happening?  Or is existing non-NaN data getting obliterated?

Comment: I can define another empty dataframe `df0=pd.DataFrame()` and append the `'temp_degF'` values to it: `df0 = df0.append(pd.DataFrame({name[ii]:[data]}), ignore_index=True)`. The resulting `df0` contains the correct data with no `NaN`.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to include an empty df as a special case. If you have an empty df, you won't have any existing columns to fill. The NaN values can appear because Pandas needs to put something into a column and there is no value yet. So if you have df1 with only col1 and you append df2 with only col2, then Pandas has nothing to put in col1 for the rows in df2, and nothing to put in col2 for the rows in df1 -- so uses NaN.